# AVD Manager Disappeared after enabling VT-X in bios

Tags: android-studio

Initially AVD Manager was there when I'm installing Android Studio for the first time and it said VT-X is disabled. So I went to bios and enabled it. Now I can't even see the AVD Managericon in Android studio.

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

Finally after several attempts, I able to run the AVD from Android Studio.
I had to uninstall Android Studio along with all the cached files and user settings and everything (including path variables).

Then when I re-install Android studio, everything worked as expected.